# Affine Paved Affine Varieties; not Affine Space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an algebraic variety.  If there is a finite ascending chain of Zariski closed sets $\emptyset=V_0\subset V_1\subset \cdots \subset V_n=V$ such that $V_i-V_{i-1}$ is a fintie disjoint union of copies of affine space $\mathbb{A}^i$ we say $V$ is *affine paved* (so $V$ is "algebraically cellular").

Note: there are non-equivalent variations of this definition (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186832/optimal-definition-of-paving-by-affine-spaces)).

One can deduce that an affine paved variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) has no odd cohomology and its even cohomology is free abelian.

Examples:

1. Finite disjoint unions of affine space are affine paved.  Let's call these examples "trivial."
2. Projective space is affine paved.
3. The Bruhat cells in a flag variety show there are interesting projective examples.

> Question: Are there non-trivial affine paved affine varieties?

This very well might be a silly question.  Perhaps the affine cone over an affine paved projective variety always works?  It doesn't seem clear to me, and I figured someone out there might have thought about such examples before (Google doesn't seem to know any).

Comment: what do you call "non-trivial"?

Comment: Any affine variety containing $\mathbb{A}^n$ as an open subset must be $\mathbb{A}^n$ itself. An affine open embedding corresponds to a localization at the level of rings, but there are no non-constant invertible functions in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Comment: @dhy This is wrong. That shows that $\mathbb{A}^n$ can not be a principal open, but it can be the complement of a nonprincipal hypersurface. I'll put up an example shortly.

Comment: (Just deleted my answer: I didn't read carefully: you're looking for *affine* varieties that are affinely paved)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One example is $uw = v(v+1)$. The equations $u=v=0$ cut out an $\mathbb{A}^1$, and the complement is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$ by the map $(x,y) \mapsto (y, xy-1, x(xy-1))$. Note that the hypersurface $u=v=0$ is not principal; by dhy's comment, it can't be.

More generally, any of the Danielewski surfaces $u w^k = \prod_{i=1}^r (v-\alpha_i)$, with the $\alpha_i$ distinct, should be paveable with one $\mathbb{A}^2$ and $(r-1)$ copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$.

I wrote a [related blogpost](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/the-plane-is-not-maximally-affine/). Much good discussion in the comments!